# Parsing XML files using element tree

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I Would like to parse an XML file in order to get the information as variables for further studies.

One part of the XML looks like this:

```
'''<SchedulingPeriod ID="sprint01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="competition.xsd">
  <StartDate>2010-01-01</StartDate>
  <EndDate>2010-01-28</EndDate>
  <Skills>
    <Skill>Nurse</Skill>
  </Skills>
  <ShiftTypes>
    <Shift ID="E">
      <StartTime>06:30:00</StartTime>
      <EndTime>14:30:00</EndTime>
      <Description>Early</Description>
      <Skills>
        <Skill>Nurse</Skill>
      </Skills>
    </Shift>
'''
```

I cant extract all the informations from the root element 3 which is ShiftTypes. My code looks like this but unfortunately I cannot extract the information shift type ID and skills:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlfile = 'sprint01.xml'

tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

for x in root[3]:
    print('StartTime: ', x.find('StartTime').text)
    print('EndTime: ', x.find('EndTime').text)
    print('Description', x.find('Description').text)
```

Thank you and if you have suggestions on how to store these elements and would really appreciate it.
Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to extract ID attribute:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('a.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    if child.tag == 'ShiftTypes':
        for i in child:
            print ('Here is the ID: ', i.attrib)
            for j in i:
                if j.tag == 'StartTime':
                    print ('Here is StartTime:', j.text)
                elif j.tag == 'EndTime':
                    print ('Here is EndTime:', j.text)
                elif j.tag == 'Description':
                    print ('Here is Description:', j.text)
```

```
Here is the ID:  {'ID': 'E'}
Here is StartTime: 06:30:00
Here is EndTime: 14:30:00
Here is Description: Early
```

Here is a useful tutorial about parsing XML data:

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-xml-elementtree